# How to get media:thumbnail from Youtube API in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, youtube-api, windows-phone, atom-feed

I'm trying to get the thumbnail from an atom feed from youtube. 
Here is my code:

```
XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
XNamespace media = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/";
var YTitems = from entry in document.Descendants(atom + "entry")
              select new RSSFeed
              {
                   Image = entry.Element(media + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value,
                   Title = entry.Element(atom + "title").Value,
                   Description = entry.Element(atom + "content").Value
              };
YoutubeList.ItemsSource = YTitems.ToList();
```

But when trying to load the feed, I am getting this error:

```
NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

It works without the `"Image = entry.element(......"`, so the problem is probably there.
(example of the feed [here](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/hocgaming/uploads).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using this:

```
ImageSRC = entry.Element(media + "group").Element(media + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value
```